# Bootstrap accordion not working without BS-panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to create BS accordion without BS panel formationg. Here ir code:

```
<div id="accordion">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a></br>
      <div id="collapse1" class=" collapse">
       text1</div>
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 1</a></br>
      <div id="collapse2" class=" collapse ">
        text2</div>
  </div>
```

Collapse does happen, but data-parent attribute does not work. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oma1dvpc/). If some one could point what have I missed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that bootstraps collapse-JS-function is using the panel-class.

you can solve your issue using JavaScript:

```
$("a[data-parent='#accordion']").on("click", function() {
    var active = $(this).attr("href");
    active = $(active);
    $(".collapse").each(function() {
        if (!$(this).is(active)) {
            $(this).collapse('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/oma1dvpc/1/